# Proof $(\text{im} A^\top)^\bot = \ker A$

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

We are in the euclidean vectorspace $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the euclidean scalar product.
Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m*n}, \text{im} A := \text{im} (\varphi_A)$ and $\ker A := \ker(\varphi_A)$.

Prove $$(\text{im} A^\top)^\bot = \ker A$$

I have no clue on where i should even start, so any help or hints are welcome.

Comment: You seem to have some typesetting errors corresponding to the use of some undefined operator \im. Can you please edit your post to correct the typesetting.

Comment: @user2628206 yup, have corrected it.

Comment: The image of a matrix is the space generated by its columns. Thus, $(\mathrm{Im} A^\intercal)^\perp$ is the space that is orthogonal to every row of $A.$ On the other hand, the entries of $Av$ are the inner product between the rows of $A$ and $v.$ Thus, being orthogonal to all the rows is equivalent to belonging in the kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\operatorname{ker}(A)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: Ax=0\}$,

$\operatorname{ran}(A^\intercal)=\{A^\intercal y:y\in\mathbb{R}^m\}$,

$\big(\operatorname{ran}(A^\intercal)\big)^\perp=\{z\in\mathbb{R}^n: \langle z, A^\intercal y\rangle =0, \,\text{for all}\, y\in\mathbb{R}^m\}$.

where $\langle h,k\rangle:= k^\intercal h$ denotes the standard  *inner* product in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Notice that $x\in\operatorname{ker}(A)$ iff
$$0=\langle Ax,y\rangle=y^\intercal Ax=(A^\intercal y)^\intercal x=\langle x, A^\intercal y\rangle$$
for all $y\in \mathbb{R}^m$. This equivalent to $x\in\operatorname{ker}(A)$ iff $x\in \big(\operatorname{ran}(A)\big)^\perp$.

---

This result is valid in any linear space with inner product, for example in Hilbert spaces.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The main notational observation is that if the rows of $A$ are given by the vectors $\mathbf{a}_k$, then $\text{im}(A^\top) = \text{span}_{\Bbb R}(\mathbf{a}_k)$. [Why?]

For instance, the inclusion $(\text{im}( A^\top))^\bot \subseteq \ker A$ is equivalent to $$\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{a}_k=0 \text{ for all }k \text{ and all } \mathbf{x}\in\ker(A).$$
I encourage you these two are indeed equivalent and verify the "main notational observation" above. Then the plan is to write a similar-looking statement for the other inclusion $(\text{im}( A^\top))^\bot \supseteq \ker A$, and prove both.

Comment: At an even higher level: this is a problem that once you understand the notation, it almost becomes hard to write down the proof because "there's nothing to say". Don't worry too much about being convincing; the main point is to unravel the notation. (Actually, the result is important in and of itself, but as an exercise, this is the point.)